# Which deity is associated with knowledge, intelligence ,omniscience ,intellect all at once?

Tags: shiva, hanuman, ganesha, durga, saraswati

We know that Rama devotee Hanuman is the bestower of knowledge, Maa Saraswati is the bestower of literature, Maa Durga and lord Shiva as the bestower of omniscience and omnipotence and Lord Ganesha as the bestower of intelligence. I wanted to know is their any specific deity who can bestow every quality mentioned above ? I also wanted to know whom to worship in order to get tremendous luck and success in our life?

**Note**- I am hardworking but still to get a blessing is highly missing in my life and that is why I am asking the following question. Thank you.